# How to get the data I need from the table at the request of the user, telegram bot on java, spring-boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, telegram-bot

**Tell me how to transfer a specific row from the mysql table at the user's request with a command, for example /help, which will respond to his request in a telegram bot, written in java, spring boot?**

```
 private  void sendAds() {
    //Список обьявлений, получение всех записей что есть в нашей таблице
    var ads = adsRepository.findAll();

    //Ищем всех юзеров и отправляем им всем сообщение
    var users = userRepository.findAll();

    //Каждому юзеру мы отправляем сообщение , берем чат id и потом переменную textToSend которая ищет
    // по подстроке все что начинаеться после пробела команды /send
    for (Ads ad : ads)
        for (User user : users) {
            prepareAndSendMessage(user.getChatId(), ad.getAd());
        }
    //Проходим по каждой строке столбца product и проходим по всему списку users,после возвращаем сообщение всем юзерам с chat id
    for (Ads product : ads) {
        for (User user : users) {
            prepareAndSendMessage(user.getChatId(), product.getProduct());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).